# Webservices engine is not started when deploying SOAP web service in Glassfish 4

Tags: soap, glassfish

I am learning about SOAP web services and have written a simple dynamic web app with a plain old java class annotated with @WebService and @WebMethod but when the application is deployed to Glassfish 4, only the "web" engine is showing and not "webservice". Hence I am unable to access any tester page or link to WSDL.

Have already checked out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232797/when-i-run-the-application-only-web-engine-is-running-in-glassfish-webservi), but the proposed answer did not help me, as I have checked and have the full Glassfish profile installed.

I have tried redeploying multiple times and tested this on both my Windows and OSX systems with equivalent setups and I am still encountering the same issue. I am using Eclipse Kepler. I have just installed the latest Glassfish update.

Hoping someone has found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Having the same issue. Have you ever managed to figure it out?

Comment: I did not really manage to find a real solution. But when I upgraded my PC to Windows 8, and reinstalled Eclipse and Java EE, the issue was mysteriously resolved. Not a real solution, I know.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, in my case i had used JAX-WS 2.2.6 inside libraries what produced this unstable behavior. Just don't use anything about JAX-WS if you are using JDK 7, don´t use anything else then natives JAX-WS. This took me days of work to find out... If this is not the exact solution for you, you should try to change your libraries (other JAR files)... one by one... Good lucky!

Answer (score 1):

You must have downloaded the 'Web Profile' version of GlassFish. Download the 'Full Profile' version and deploy your application once again. You should be able to find 'webservices' under Engines.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your classes are not compiling under default build/classes directory.

Do either of the following:
Right click on your project > Build Project.
or Go to eclipse menu > Project > Build Automatically

Now redeploy your application again. webservices engine should be visible along with web engine.

Answer (score 0):

After Making the changes in Class. Steps:

1. Go to eclipse menu -> Project -> Build Automatically
2. Right Click on Project -> Run As -> Run On Server.